# Is it possible to pivot on two columns? (if that's even the correct way to ask this?)

Tags: sql-server-2012, pivot

I am trying to create a report that prints our home room counts in a readable format. We currently have an Excel Template that is manually filled out but I would like to automate this process within SQL so we can just pull the report from the database. Since this is public school data I won't post my sub-query or "real" data but I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I have a subquery that pulls student_ID, School_Title, Grade_Level, and HomeRoom that I named Data. For the purposes of this dicussion, let's assume Data is actually a table in my database. I have been working on using a pivot, but it doesn't seem to do what I need. We have multiple schools, each with multiple homerooms per grade level. There are different numbers of homerooms per grade level per school depending on the size of the school. (So School 1 might have only 2 Kindergarten homerooms, but School4 might have 4 homerooms for Kindergarten).

Data looks like this:

```
Student_ID     School_Title    Grade_Level    HomeRoom
12345          School1         KA             HR1
23456          School1         KP             HR2
34567          School1         01             HR3
45678          School1         01             HR4
......
56789          School7         06             HR100
```

The query I am using right now is (in SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT *
FROM Data
PIVOT (Count(student_ID)
   FOR GRADE_LEVEL IN ([KA],[KP],[01],[02],[03],[04],[05],[06])
   ) as PivotStudents
ORDER BY School_Title
```

But what I get out is:

```
School_Title   HomeRoom   KA   KP   01   02   03   04   05   06
School 1       HR1        25   0    0    0    0    0    0    0
School 1       HR2        0    26   0    0    0    0    0    0
School 1       HR3        0    0    19   0    0    0    0    0
School 1       HR4        0    0    21   0    0    0    0    0
....
School 7       HR100      0    0    0    0    0    0    0    27
```

What I want to get out is:

```
School_Title   HR   KA   HR   KP   HR   01  HR   02...
School 1       HR1  25   HR2  26   HR3  19  HR5  23
School 1                           HR4  21
...
School 7       HR91 19   HR92 19   HR93 20  HR98 21
School 7       HR94 17   HR95 23   HR96 18  HR99 24
School 7                           HR97 22
```

I don't care which are grouped together "in a row". So, in my head, HR3 happened to be the first grade 01 homeroom found so it's in row 1. But HR4 is also a grade 01 homeroom at School 1 and is the next one found so it goes into row 2.

It is possible for a homeroom to have multiple grade levels too (though only in 2 cases but I need to account for it being possible).

So basically, is the output I'm going for even possible within SQL? Do I need to get out of the database into Crystal or something to be able to "place" the data where I want it to go or can I give SQL enough information to format it how I want.

Thanks!
DBs

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly get what you're asking. You want them in the same row, whatever the order? Or what do you want exactly?

Comment: Essentially I want to get rid of a lot of zeros displaying :) So whereas in the first table (with my current SQL) each homeroom is a row and the number of students per grade level is displayed.
Whereas in the 2nd table (what I would like ideally) it lists the first homeroom found per grade level. So the first homeroom found (order by alpha by homeroom name would be fine) for that grade level displays in that grade level column in row 1 and the second homeroom for that grade level displays in that grade level column in row 2...

Comment: So basically a line per school might do it? If so, you should try `GROUP BY School_Title`

Comment: I wish! If each school only had one homeroom per grade level, i would have just went with group bys and order bys and not messed with pivot at all.
I'm honestly beginning to think what I'm trying to do is just not possible within SQL alone...

Comment: Oh ok, I get it. Could you provide us with an example of how the `Data` table is constructed?

Comment: edited question to include sample of Data table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using aggregates with case statements.. the key will be to add a DENSE_RANK column to your data to separate the aggregates into rows.

```
SELECT
    [School_Title],
    [HR] = MAX(CASE WHEN [Grade_Level] = 'KA' THEN [HomeRoom] END),
    [KA] = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Grade_Level] = 'KA' THEN [Student_ID] END),
    [HR] = MAX(CASE WHEN [Grade_Level] = 'KP' THEN [HomeRoom] END),
    [KP] = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Grade_Level] = 'KP' THEN [Student_ID] END),
    [HR] = MAX(CASE WHEN [Grade_Level] = '01' THEN [HomeRoom] END),
    [01] = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Grade_Level] = '01' THEN [Student_ID] END)
    -- etc
FROM
    (
        SELECT  *,
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [School_Title], [Grade_Level] ORDER BY [HomeRoom]) Rn
        FROM    [Data]
    ) d
GROUP BY [School_Title], [RN]
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee5d43/2)

Comment: Thanks! Trying to modify now :)

Comment: Hrm, this gets me MUCH closer than I was with my PIVOT try, but still not quite. This appears to only get me one row per school so it grabs the top homeroom per building that fits that case. So if we have 4 KA homerooms at School 1, it is only picking the top Homeroom. But it does list school, then HR1 name for KA, then HR1 count for KA, then HR2 name for KP, then HR2 count for KP, and so on. I'm assuming it's the "MAX" that it doing that...

Comment: only way it would do that is if you didnt include the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [School_Title], [Grade_Level] ORDER BY [HomeRoom])` thats in my answer, or you left off the `GROUP BY Rn`

Comment: you're right, i had taken the group by Rn off, because it wasn't counting the actual students and was fiddling with it! Regardless, i used your idea of case statements and maxes and just did the counts within the sub query so that I didn't have to mess with that within the case statements. Worked like a charm!!

Comment: @DianneBates I see what you're saying.. actually just changing my query to DENSE_RANK() instead of ROW_NUMBER() would solve that problem also

Comment: Thanks, I'll look up Dense_Rank, never used it before :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above by Jamie, but changed the Count to happen with the Data Subquery and used Max for all the case statements so...

```
Select
   School_Title,
   [HR1]=MAX(CASE WHEN [grade_level]='KA' THEN [HomeRoom] END),
   [KA]=MAX(CASE WHEN [grade_level]='KA' THEN [Number] END),
   [HR2]=MAX(CASE WHEN [grade_level]='KP' THEN [HomeRoom] END),
   [KP]=MAX(CASE WHEN [grade_level]='KP' THEN [Number] END),
   ..... etc.
From (
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY School_Title, Grade_LEvel ORDER by HomeRoom) Rn
   from (
      select count(student_id) as Number, School_Title, Grade_Level, HomeRoom
      from Data
      group by School_Title, Grade_Level, HomeRoom) data2
GROUP BY School_Title, Rn
ORDER BY SCHOOL_Title
```

I need to add some IsNull somewhere along the line so that a school that has 4 homerooms of grade 1 but only 3 homerooms of grade 2 doesn't have NULL/NULL chilling in the last row for that school, but all in all, I can't believe this can actually be done in SQL!!!